# Autocomplete edit field for blackberry jde 4.6

Tags: blackberry, java-me, autocomplete

How do I create an auto-complete edit field for blackberry that works on the 4.6 jde?

I know it has to do with a fieldchangelistener and painting a floating rect on the screen, but I haven't succeeded so far.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for saying such a demotivating thing, however I would even not try to do that. You should realize that simply painting a "floating rect on the screen" is not enough - that "floating rect" shoud be a focusable field that appears **over** another fields on the screen, however this is impossible with 4.6 APIs.

Comment: It's not impossible, but would take a reasonable amount of work.  This probably exceeds what can be answered via SO, though.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to make autocomplete field for Contacts.

1. Make an object which stores all contact info
2. Make a CustomAutoCompleteFld class with extends Field.
3. When this field is clicked its fieldchanged() will get invoked.
4. Now display a popupScreen with custom width n ht wrt to the records to be shown. This popupScreen is your 'Floating rect'.
5. The records to be added should themselves be for eg: clickable LabelFields
   The records to be displayed depend on your 'Search algo' performed on the obj storing your Contacts info. U'll have to implement your own Search algo.
6. Now on clicking the record i.e., the labelfld, invoke the fieldChanged of the LabelFld and do further processing